# How to write connection string in class file using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, class

I have created registration form in asp.net web application and created database in sqlserver.

### My button click event are:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fname = txtFirst.Text;
    string lname = txtLast.Text;
    string middle = txtMiddle.Text;
    string dob = txtDOB.Text;                     
    string add1 = txtAdd1.Text;
    string add2 = txtAdd2.Text;
    string dateofjoin = txtDateofjoin.Text;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Employee"].ToString());
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EmployeeRegister", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", fname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", middle);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", dob);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", add1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", add2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofjoin", dateofjoin);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", CheckActive.Checked ? "1" : "0");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();                      
}
```

so I have created the Connection.cs file,In that i wanna write the connection string on class file and call it on button click event so is that possible?

Comment: And why you want to keep SQL connection string in class file? It should be in app.config or web.config file.

Comment: app.config or web.config are easily accessible, and so it might be safe to keep it inside cs page, so tat others cant see it.

Comment: Holding connection string in config files are preferable in most cases. Always go with config file for confidential values.

Comment: @sanatsathyan, Config files are NOT easily accessible as they are not served up by IIS. However if security is an issue connection strings should stored outside the app and encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your connection.cs class, do :

```
public class Connection
{
    public static readonly string ConnectionString = "your connection string here";
}
```

And do the button click event like:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fname = txtFirst.Text;
        string lname = txtLast.Text;
        string middle = txtMiddle.Text;
        string dob = txtDOB.Text;
        string add1 = txtAdd1.Text;
        string add2 = txtAdd2.Text;
        string dateofjoin = txtDateofjoin.Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EmployeeRegister", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", fname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", middle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", dob);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", add1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", add2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofjoin", dateofjoin);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", CheckActive.Checked ? "1" : "0");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: What's to stop someone decompiling your DLL and grabbing the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
string connectionString ="Your connection string comes here";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EmployeeRegister", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", fname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", middle);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", dob);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", add1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", add2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofjoin", dateofjoin);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", CheckActive.Checked ? "1" : "0");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```